# Increase timeout for cassandra native transport threads?

Tags: cassandra

From the Cassandra documentation [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__native_transport_max_threads)

> **native_transport_max_threads**
>
> The maximum number of thread handling requests. Similar to rpc_max_threads, but this property differs as follows:
>
> - The default for native_transport_max_threads is 128; the default for rpc_max_threads is unlimited.
> - There is no corresponding native_transport_min_threads.
> - Cassandra stops idle native transport threads after 30 seconds.

I wonder if there's any way to increase the timeout before cassandra kills idle threads? I can't find anything in the docs, but someone might know of an un(der)documented setting?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: So I can have it open for up to 60s without sending a heartbeat... requirements and reasons :/

Comment: Well, then I am asking differently: what problem does the 30 s timeout cause for you?